# Сan you help write program in in C# that matches the translation of a phrase to English phrases in an XML document?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xquery

I have a string array with an english version and a string array with a russian translation
XML document looks like this

```
<messages>
  <message id="1">
    <variant language="en_US">Customer</variant>
    <variant language="ru_RU"/>
  </message>
  <message id="2">
    <variant language="en_US">Model</variant>
    <variant language="ru_RU"/>
  </message>
</messages>
```

I tried to first delete the node with the ru_RU attribute and write a new node with the translation, but I got the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
mlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\TestZad2\TestZad2\ViewerMessages.xml");          
XmlElement element = xml.DocumentElement;
                                                                                              
if(element.Attributes["variant language"].Value == "ru_RU")

{
      
xml.RemoveChild(element);

}

xml.Save(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\TestZad2\TestZad2\ViewerMessages.xml");
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What actual result do you want, and where are you going to get the translation from?

Comment: Which do you have? Two string arrays or an XML document? If you have XML then use `XDocument`, not `XmlDocument`.

Comment: I bet that when that exception is thrown, you can tell what line it is being thrown from. We'd like to know too! That said, I bet it's `if(element.Attributes...`. Have you debugged this at all. You load a document and then look at the first element (the only one you ever look at) at look at its _attributes_. It has none, so boom. Think about what you are trying to do. With XML, you have a hierarchy of elements, and you probably want to traverse them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

```
    var document = XDocument.Parse(@"<messages>
  <message id=""1"">
    <variant language=""en_US"">Customer</variant>
    <variant language=""ru_RU""/>
  </message>
  <message id=""2"">
    <variant language=""en_US"">Model</variant>
    <variant language=""ru_RU""/>
  </message>
</messages>");
    
    var variant =
    (
        from m in document.Root.Elements("message")
        where (int)m.Attribute("id") == 1
        from v in m.Elements("variant")
        where (string)v.Attribute("language") == "ru_RU"
        select v
    ).FirstOrDefault();
    
    if (variant != null)
    {
        variant.SetValue("Клиент");
    }
```

And that gives me:

```
<messages>
  <message id="1">
    <variant language="en_US">Customer</variant>
    <variant language="ru_RU">Клиент</variant>
  </message>
  <message id="2">
    <variant language="en_US">Model</variant>
    <variant language="ru_RU" />
  </message>
</messages>
```